# Tikzpicture in wrapfigure affects rest of the pages

Tags: tikz-pgf, wrapfigure

The wrapfigure does its job. I wanted two tikzpictures to be at the right side of the page. Like this:[image]

But then if I look at the next page, it's like the wrapfigure just goes on at the right side:
[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{wrapfig}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
\section{Een mier op een piramide}
\end{center}
\hrulefill \\
De piramide in de figuur hiernaast heeft een vierkant grondvlak $ABCD$ met zijde 1. Het punt $T$ ligt loodrecht boven het punt $D$. $TD = \sqrt{2}.$ \\ \\
Een mier loopt van punt A via een punt op de ribbe $BT$ naar punt $C$, zo dat de weg $A - P - C$ zo kort mogelijk is. \\
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{5cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=above left:A] (A) at (0,0,4);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (4,0,4);
\coordinate [label=above right:C] (C) at (4,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above left:D] (D) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:T] (T) at (0,5,0);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (3,2,3.5);

\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,5,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,0,4);
\draw (0,5,0) -- (0,0,4) -- (4,0,4) -- (0,5,0) -- (4,0,0) -- (4,0,4);
\draw (0,0,4) -- (3,2,3.5) -- (4,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=below left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=left:$\sqrt{3}$] (X) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate [label=below:$1$] (X) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=below left:T] (T) at (0,5);
\coordinate [label=above left:$2$] (X) at (2.75,2.5);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (2.16,1.43);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (3,0) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (2.16,1.43);
\draw (2.22,1.3) -- (2.13,1.24) -- (2.06,1.35);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection*{7. Bereken exact de lengte van lijnstuk $TP$.}
$BD = \sqrt{1^2+1^2}= \sqrt{2}$ \\ \\
In $\triangle BDT$ is $TD=\sqrt{2}$ en $BD = \sqrt{2}$. \\
Dus $BT=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{2+2}=2$. \\ \\
In $\triangle ADT$ is $AT=\sqrt{1^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{3}$.
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
De oppervlakte van $\triangle ABT$ hiernaast is $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\
De oppervlakte kun je ook berekenen door: \\ $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot BT \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
$\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
$AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
In $\triangle APT$ is $TP=\sqrt{(\sqrt{3})^2-(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3})^2}=1\frac{1}{2}$.

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
  \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (6,6);
  \draw[-] (-3,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
  \draw[-] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
  \foreach \x in {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$}; 
  \draw[blue] (-2,4) node[below left] {$k$};
  \draw[black] (4,5) node[above left] {$A$}; 
  \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (6,6);
  \draw[scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,blue,domain=-3:6] plot ({\x},{(-4/3)*\x});
  \draw[dashed,scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,red,domain=-3:6] plot ({\x},{(3/4)*\x+2});
  \draw[fill=black](4,5) circle(0.5mm);
  \draw[red](-0.96,1.28) -- (-1.04,1.386666666667) -- (-0.94,1.46) -- (-0.86,1.355) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\begin{center}
\section{Bronnen en reflectie}
\end{center}
\hrulefill \\
\subsection{Bronnen}
\subsubsection{Internet}
Bij het maken van deze opdracht heb ik de volgende sites gebruikt, u kunt erop klikken:
\begin{itemize}
\item \url{http://www.texample.net/tikz/}
\item \url{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/}
\item \url{https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Main_Page}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeD/VD09%20Lijnen%20en%20cirkels.pdf}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeB/VB07%20Differentiaalrekening.pdf}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeB/VB09%20Exponentiele%20en%20logaritmische%20functies.pdf} 
\\ \\
Als ik er echt niet uit kwam, stelde ik een vraag op een forum speciaal voor \LaTeX:
\item \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Boeken}
Ik heb ook gebruik gemaakt van een aantal boeken, namelijk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Werken met \LaTeX, geschreven door D.C. van der Leeden
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde D deel 3: gemengde opgaven H9 opgave 2bc; uitleg op blz. 18
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde B deel 2: gemengde opgaven H5 opgave 4a, 4b; gemengde opgaven H7 opgave 29ac 
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde B deel 3: gemengde opgaven H9 opgave 1b, 2bc
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Toetsen}
Ik heb ook een aantal opgaven uit de toetsen van dit jaar en vorig jaar:
\begin{itemize}
\item Wiskunde B VWO 5 H7 en H9 t/m opgave 11
\item Wiskunde D VWO 4 H1 en H2
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Reflectie}
Het installeren van \LaTeX was geen probleem. Echter, toen we het op 6 november op moesten sturen kreeg ik foutmeldingen over de pakketten die niet geïnstalleerd zouden zijn, zoals tikz. Uiteindelijk begon ik rond 10 november en elke dag werkte ik er ongeveer een uurtje aan om \LaTeX onder de knie te krijgen. \\
Begin deze week heb ik eindelijk tikz en alle andere pakketten kunnen installeren waardoor ik de grafieken e.d. erin kon zetten. Ik heb in totaal ongeveer 14 uur gewerkt aan dit document. \\
Een saaie opdracht vond ik het zeker niet. Ik ben altijd al ge"{i}nteresseerd geweest in computers en wiskunde, een combinatie daarvan is daarom extra leuk! \\ 
Het hebben van informatica als vak was hierbij ook een voordeel, je kan \LaTeX \ code namelijk vergelijken met HTML. \\ \\
Al met al vond ik het een zeer leerzame en leuke opdracht!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE doesn't really represent the screenshots you posted. Add some [Lorem Ipsum](http://www.lipsum.com/) text (if you don't want to add your actual text) to your code example to reproduce it.

Comment: eek don't do `\begin{center}
\section{Een mier op een piramide}
\end{center}` !!

Comment: `wrapfigure` tends to do the wrong thing if used in the wrong place. The 'wrong place' includes too near a page break.

Comment: @Alenanno the whole code is there now

Comment: @DavidCarlisle whole code is there now

Comment: @JohnKormylo whole code is there now

Comment: Use \WFclear before \newpage

Comment: No it isn't: `! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \dfrac`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, remember to provide all packages in order to be able to typeset your MWE properly, since yours lacked the packages `hyperref`  and `amssymb, amsmath` causing some errors as highlighted in the comments.

I also added a package (`sectsty`) and a command in the preamble in order to center your section headings, `\begin{center}` is not the appropriate way to do this.

I fixed your problem by enclosing the Tikz pictures up to the end of the subsection, by using the `\begingroup` and `\endgroup`. See also [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/27699/4778) to read more about it. The difference is that the `\setlength\intextsep{0pt}` command is not needed in this case (as far as I've noticed), so you can just use the two tags above.

[image]

[image: figure 2]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{sectsty} % Allows the commands for centering section headings

\allsectionsfont{\centering} % This centers section headings

\begin{document}
\section{Een mier op een piramide}

\hrulefill \\
De piramide in de figuur hiernaast heeft een vierkant grondvlak $ABCD$ met zijde 1. Het punt $T$ ligt loodrecht boven het punt $D$. $TD = \sqrt{2}.$ \\ \\
Een mier loopt van punt A via een punt op de ribbe $BT$ naar punt $C$, zo dat de weg $A - P - C$ zo kort mogelijk is. \\
\begingroup
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}{3cm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=above left:A] (A) at (0,0,4);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (4,0,4);
\coordinate [label=above right:C] (C) at (4,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above left:D] (D) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate [label=above:T] (T) at (0,5,0);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (3,2,3.5);

\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (4,0,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,5,0);
\draw[color=gray, style=dashed] (0,0) -- (0,0,4);
\draw (0,5,0) -- (0,0,4) -- (4,0,4) -- (0,5,0) -- (4,0,0) -- (4,0,4);
\draw (0,0,4) -- (3,2,3.5) -- (4,0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.75]
\coordinate [label=below left:A] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate [label=left:$\sqrt{3}$] (X) at (0,2.5);
\coordinate [label=below:$1$] (X) at (1.5,0);
\coordinate [label=below right:B] (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate [label=below left:T] (T) at (0,5);
\coordinate [label=above left:$2$] (X) at (2.75,2.5);
\coordinate [label=above right:P] (P) at (2.16,1.43);

\draw (0,0) -- (0,5) -- (3,0) -- (0,0);
\draw (0,0) -- (2.16,1.43);
\draw (2.22,1.3) -- (2.13,1.24) -- (2.06,1.35);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{wrapfigure}

\subsection*{7. Bereken exact de lengte van lijnstuk $TP$.} 

$BD = \sqrt{1^2+1^2}= \sqrt{2}$ \\ \\
In $\triangle BDT$ is $TD=\sqrt{2}$ en $BD = \sqrt{2}$. \\
Dus $BT=\sqrt{(\sqrt{2})^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{2+2}=2$. \\ \\
In $\triangle ADT$ is $AT=\sqrt{1^2+(\sqrt{2})^2}=\sqrt{3}$.
\\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ \\ 
De oppervlakte van $\triangle ABT$ hiernaast is $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 1 \cdot \sqrt{3}=\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
De oppervlakte kun je ook berekenen door: \\ $\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot BT \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\ \\
$\dfrac{1}{2} \cdot 2 \cdot AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\
$AP = \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{3}$ \\
In $\triangle APT$ is $TP=\sqrt{(\sqrt{3})^2-(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3})^2}=1\frac{1}{2}$.
\endgroup

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(current bounding box.center)}]
  \draw[step=1cm,color=gray!20] (-3,-2) grid (6,6);
  \draw[-] (-3,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$x$};
  \draw (0,0) node[below left] {$O$};
  \draw[-] (0,-2) -- (0,6) node[above] {$y$};
  \foreach \x in {-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (\x cm,1pt) -- (\x cm,-1pt) node[anchor=north] {$\x$};
  \foreach \y in {-2, -1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
    \draw (1pt,\y cm) -- (-1pt,\y cm) node[anchor=east] {$\y$}; 
  \draw[blue] (-2,4) node[below left] {$k$};
  \draw[black] (4,5) node[above left] {$A$}; 
  \clip (-3,-2) rectangle (6,6);
  \draw[scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,blue,domain=-3:6] plot ({\x},{(-4/3)*\x});
  \draw[dashed,scale=1,smooth,variable=\x,red,domain=-3:6] plot ({\x},{(3/4)*\x+2});
  \draw[fill=black](4,5) circle(0.5mm);
  \draw[red](-0.96,1.28) -- (-1.04,1.386666666667) -- (-0.94,1.46) -- (-0.86,1.355) -- cycle ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage

\section{Bronnen en reflectie}

\hrulefill \\
\subsection{Bronnen}
\subsubsection{Internet}
Bij het maken van deze opdracht heb ik de volgende sites gebruikt, u kunt erop klikken:
\begin{itemize}
\item \url{http://www.texample.net/tikz/}
\item \url{http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/}
\item \url{https://nl.sharelatex.com/learn/Main_Page}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeD/VD09%20Lijnen%20en%20cirkels.pdf}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeB/VB07%20Differentiaalrekening.pdf}
\item \url{http://www.wiskunde-uitwerkingen.nl/Vwo/wiskundeB/VB09%20Exponentiele%20en%20logaritmische%20functies.pdf} 
\\ \\
Als ik er echt niet uit kwam, stelde ik een vraag op een forum speciaal voor \LaTeX:
\item \url{http://tex.stackexchange.com}
\end{itemize}

\subsubsection{Boeken}
Ik heb ook gebruik gemaakt van een aantal boeken, namelijk:
\begin{itemize}
\item Werken met \LaTeX, geschreven door D.C. van der Leeden
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde D deel 3: gemengde opgaven H9 opgave 2bc; uitleg op blz. 18
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde B deel 2: gemengde opgaven H5 opgave 4a, 4b; gemengde opgaven H7 opgave 29ac 
\item Getal en Ruimte wiskunde B deel 3: gemengde opgaven H9 opgave 1b, 2bc
\end{itemize}
\subsubsection{Toetsen}
Ik heb ook een aantal opgaven uit de toetsen van dit jaar en vorig jaar:
\begin{itemize}
\item Wiskunde B VWO 5 H7 en H9 t/m opgave 11
\item Wiskunde D VWO 4 H1 en H2
\end{itemize}

\subsection{Reflectie}
Het installeren van \LaTeX was geen probleem. Echter, toen we het op 6 november op moesten sturen kreeg ik foutmeldingen over de pakketten die niet geïnstalleerd zouden zijn, zoals tikz. Uiteindelijk begon ik rond 10 november en elke dag werkte ik er ongeveer een uurtje aan om \LaTeX onder de knie te krijgen. \\
Begin deze week heb ik eindelijk tikz en alle andere pakketten kunnen installeren waardoor ik de grafieken e.d. erin kon zetten. Ik heb in totaal ongeveer 14 uur gewerkt aan dit document. \\
Een saaie opdracht vond ik het zeker niet. Ik ben altijd al ge"{i}nteresseerd geweest in computers en wiskunde, een combinatie daarvan is daarom extra leuk! \\ 
\end{document}
```